# Oracle mview refresh taking long time

Tags: materialized-view, oracle-19c

the customer I work for is used to launch a script to refresh mviews on its db.
Refresh command for all mviews is issued in the following way:

DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('"OWNER"."MVIEW"','C');

I noticed through Enterprise Manager that the insert command is the one that is taking longer (the delete is ok).
I also observed a "enq: JI - contention" occurrence but reading the note on Oracle Support looks like is an ordinary behaviour during refresh: a lock on the mview table is applied to prevent other session to issue other refresh commands..

[image]

Session 854 was executing the insert, while session 72 was executing a script launching the refresh commands like the one above.
No other contention situations observed.

I tried tuning the insert statements but even increasing the TIME_LIMIT parameter the command fails with ORA-13639 (timeout).
Meanwhile, I suggested to add the atomic_refresh=>TRUE.

Is my approach correct (sqltuning)? Should I analyze something else?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this have to use a complete refresh? Can you tune the insert query? If you're seeing JI contention then multiple sessions are trying to do a complete refresh on the Materialized view at the same time, this would be highly unusual for something that requires a complete refresh - you would normally expect these to be handled by a scheduled job, not adhoc user sessions that block each other

Comment: For the first question I need to ask the customer, actually I don't know. 
As previously said, yes, I tried to tune the insert but the sqltuning goes timeout even increasing the TIME_LIMIT parameter.
I tried to lookup the session and I noticed that blocked one was the script and the blocking one was an insert for another mview refresh: tried to kill them both but at the moment I can't see any improvement.

Comment: Tuning the SQL in the MV definition will not help. Oracle doesn't use your SQL when running a refresh; it only uses your SQL when the MV is created. After that it builds its own dynamic SQL to refresh the content. There is no way to modify that SQL or control how Oracle generates it. At best you can add indexes or perform other indirect methods of tuning to try and improve performance.

Comment: Tuning the SQL doesn't involve changing any time limits, it means looking at the SQL, looking at the execution plan and giving it a better way of working. Killing the sessions without really understanding what's going on is probably not advisable. The SQL in the MV definition is what Oracle needs to run to refresh the MView, it's performance will directly impact the performance for the MView refresh. Please update your post with the SQL for the Mview and the execution plan it's using to refresh it.

Comment: Maybe you could post a picture of the waits as they are displayed in Enterprise Manager. If all the insert's time is spent on the enqueue wait then it is not a bad plan but just a hang on a lock. If it is a bad plan you will see a lot of CPU and I/O waits.

Comment: I updated my post with a screen from EM. 
@AndrewSayer Pardon me, just to be clear: you need me to post the mview DDL ?

Comment: Yes, mview DDL would be helpful, as well as the execution plan. The small amount of info we can see now shows your SYS session is doing some amount of waiting on resmgr:cpu quantum - you should look at how resource manager is set up, an immediate stab in the dark would be that you are generally using a lot of CPU around this time (with cpu heavy processes affected the most) so Oracle is having to artificially limit sessions to ensure important sessions get a guaranteed amount of resource. This isn't really enough to make any decisions with though.

Comment: Yes, from the observing on EM I can confirm that the insert statement is consuming a good amount of CPU (66%).
DDL attached.

Comment: Changing the MV DDL definition will only affect MV creation, not refresh. Oracle generates its own query for the refresh, which is _based_ on the DDL, but may have different hints, join construction, and other differences; there's no way to alter it or tune it directly. And yes, Oracle may (shocker!) not generate optimal code all the time in these situations.

Comment: `I tried to lookup the session and I noticed that blocked one was the script and the blocking one was an insert for another mview refresh` From your description, it sounds like one MV refresh might be deadlocked waiting on another. The only way to fix that is to get the _running_ refresh to complete and release the blocking lock. Setting atomic_refresh will probably _hurt_ that by forcing everything 
 - delete and insert - into a single transaction which takes even longer to run and release locks.